# Salesforce and microservices

Tags: architecture

For apps that harness microservices architecture, say I have custom objects 'libraries', 'categories', 'books', and I wish to keep each custom objects into different physical databases ([Database per service](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html)), and create CRUD microservices for each type of custom objects:

- How can I implement such architecture in Salesforce?
- Is it a possible or a good practice to do so in Salesforce?
- How to scale well when the number of records scales exponentially in the future with Salesforce Limit considered?

Edit:

How can I dynamically instantiate particular instances of such independent services (including the associated tables) to scale horizontally in response to dynamic loads/traffic, say, the Book table/database has much more intensive traffic (CRUD operations), and I wish the specific **Book service** has more instances than library and category services?

Comment: Have a look to this, if you find anything helpful: https://github.com/bigassforce/servicebus

Comment: Actually, I've read your question better, and I'd say that - given that with Salesforce load balancing and management is not something you're in control with or can configure, and that there's no concept of separate databases (as explained in the answer below) - possibly the architecture you're thinking doesn't apply to force.com platform unless you stretch the original idea to fit what the platform actually offers.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCa1yPzVMw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Salesforce the equivalent of a database is an org and Salesforce charge per User per month per org. So a custom object per org would get very expensive very quickly... From the link in your question, this option is suggested:

> Private-tables-per-service – each service owns a set of tables that
>   must only be accessed by that service

that amounts to discipline in the design and implementation to keep the services and tables independent of each other: seems much more appropriate for Salesforce.

On whether it is a "good practice" on Salesforce, my opinion is that you would just be using Salesforce as a web service engine and database and so not getting any advantage from the many other features of the platform. So value for money would be an issue.

On your scaling, see articles such as [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm).

**PS**

A quick Google revealed [Microservices & Salesforce - Your Next Step](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microservices-salesforce-your-next-step-paul-battisson) - this may be a good start point for further research.

**PPS**

On the scaling "Edit" point, this https://status.salesforce.com/performance illustrates the very high request (transaction) volumes that Saleasforce can handle. Each database cluster is fronted by a large number of machines and requests can be routed to any of the machines because they hold no server-side state. You do not have to configure instances: your service code will be loaded on demand in multiple machines as the request volume goes up.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It answered most of my concerns. I edited the post and added additional questions. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted!